# please give me one best solution for Use of undeclared identifier 'ECRight'

Tags: ios, objective-c

code is:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *idetifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = self.slidingViewController;

    UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondTop"];
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
        slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
}
```

Comment: your code looks fine to me, it doesn't show this error to me. You can check your library is imported properly or check at the `ECSlidingViewController.h` whether there `ECRight` is present there or not

Answer (score 0):

Did you import your library header file ?

```
#import <ECSlidingViewController.h> // from a static library or a cocoapod
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h" //if you directly copied the files in your project
```

**EDIT:**

According to [this file](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController/blob/master/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingConstants.h), the constant you are looking for is `ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight`.

Comment: my error is: Use of undeclared identifier 'ECRight'

Comment: Replace ECRight with ECSlidingViewControllerTopViewPositionAnchoredRight